# C#. Реализация Repository без использования ORM

Tags: c#, .net, orm, рефлексия

Я сделал небольшой проект, который собираюсь использовать как ORM при разработке приложений для Windows CE 5.0. Работает он довольно медленно. Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать работу моей маленькой ORM. [Ссылка на github (для .net 3.5)](https://github.com/mirypoko/RincewindORM)

Больше всего проблем с методами, возвращающими данные из БД. Хотелось бы найти более производительный способ конвертации ответа в объекты.

Нужно вносить изменения, которые будут работать на .net 3.5 compact. Например `Expression` использовать нельзя.

**Update: после замены алгоритма мапинга результатов запроса работать ORM стала быстрее, но она все равно намного медленнее EF, `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` стоит false**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой ответ вы хотите получить на поставленный вопрос? Если вы просто набираете добровольцев, то это определенно не то место где это надо делать. Если у вас конкретная проблема с кодом - покажите код и проблему.

Comment: Посмотрите реализацию маппинга в Linq To SQL (он вроде бы поддерживался на компакте). Там используется кодогенерация для маппинга из ридера в объекты - это гораздо быстрее, чем маппинг через reflection

Comment: Создайте вопрос для одного конкретного участка кода (метода), с приведением MVCE и результатов тестирования. Иначе вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: @tym32167 у меня есть вполне конкретная проблема с производительностью методов, извлекающих данные из бд. Но проект сам по себе очень медленный. Может кому-то опытному будет не лень просмотреть мой код и предложить варианты ускорения некоторых функций.

Comment: Класс  PropertyAccessor и рядом с ним: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/Mapping/Accessors.cs,c63709f2dc93d0de

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Единственным быстрым вариантом маппинга в .NET 3.5 была генерация делегатов для доступа. Можете взять за основу реализацию [PropertyAccessor.Create из Linq To SQL](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/Mapping/Accessors.cs,c63709f2dc93d0de):

Генерация делегата-геттера достаточна тривиальна.

```
Type dgetType = typeof(DGet<,>).MakeGenericType(objectType, pi.PropertyType);
// pi - ваш PropertyInfo
MethodInfo getMethod = pi.GetGetMethod(true);
Delegate dget = Delegate.CreateDelegate(dgetType, getMethod, true);
```

Для публичного сеттера (`pi.CanWrite`) все относительно просто:

```
dset = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(DSet<,>).MakeGenericType(objectType, pi.PropertyType),
    pi.GetSetMethod(true),
    true
    );
```

С приватным сеттером сложнее, придется делать кодогенериацию через emit:

```
DynamicMethod mset = new DynamicMethod(
    "xset_" + pi.Name,
    typeof(void),
    new Type[] { objectType.MakeByRefType(), pi.PropertyType },
    true
    );
ILGenerator gen = mset.GetILGenerator();
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
if (!objectType.IsValueType) {
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldind_Ref);
}
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, pi.GetSetMethod(true));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
drset = mset.CreateDelegate(typeof(DRSet<,>).MakeGenericType(objectType, pi.PropertyType));
```

`DGet` и `DSet` - это ожидаемые сигнатуры для делегатов (аналог современных `Action<>` и `Func<>`:

```
internal delegate V DGet<T, V>(T t);
internal delegate void DSet<T, V>(T t, V v);
```

Из делегатов выстраивайте цепочки для маппинга всего объекта и кэшируйте по типу, чтобы не генерировать все это при каждом маппинге.

Comment: Честно говоря то что написано в вашем ответе для меня еще слишком сложно. Я перенес классы `PropertyAccessor` и `Accessor` в свой проект, поменяв только вызываемые исключения. Использовал ваш код чтобы создать делегат dset, но как теперь мне им воспользоваться для внесения значения в поле объекта?

Comment: Простите, я затупил. Уже разобрался, спасибо большое за помощь!